# Filtering the JSON data which is received from UrlFetchApp

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, filtering

In the script, I am importing the JSON data from the API's URL, using the `UrlFetchApp.fetch`

This part of code looks next:

```
var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions);
```

And here is a shortened example of how the JSON i work with looks like:

```
[
  {
    "average": 5.76,
    "date": "2021-03-16",
    "highest": 5.88,
    "lowest": 5.41,
    "order_count": 2214,
    "volume": 5093879501
  },
  {
    "average": 5.88,
    "date": "2021-03-17",
    "highest": 5.92,
    "lowest": 5.46,
    "order_count": 2285,
    "volume": 3968980696
  },
  {
    "average": 5.68,
    "date": "2021-03-18",
    "highest": 5.91,
    "lowest": 5.6,
    "order_count": 2219,
    "volume": 3695305537
  },
  {
    "average": 5.65,
    "date": "2021-03-19",
    "highest": 5.98,
    "lowest": 5.59,
    "order_count": 2192,
    "volume": 3948557942
  }
]
```

I need to filter the above data before it goes further in a script, and my problem is that I'm getting this JSON data as an `jsondata` object, with no actual JSON code.

I consider that the most convenient way to filter data will be turning the `jsondata` into an array (in order to use ***.slice*** and ***.map*** for my filtering), and then converting the resulting array back to object to use further in a script, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You do not need to convert JSON response when you are working with JS , What do you mean about _turning the `jsondata` into an array_ ? Do you get any error during using methods for JSON data ? Is `JSON.parse()` what you want ?

Comment: Yes-I am very new, and I do not know a lot of basic things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting a JSON string and you need to use the function JSON.parse() to convert it to an object.

So, use this:

```
let jsondata = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions));
```

JSON.parse is a secure function to parse JSON strings and convert them to objects.
Now you will have an object that you can do everything with it.

```
With an object you can use many JS native functions as:
Object.keys(obj) to extract the keys
Object.values(obj) to extract the values
Object.entries(obj) to extract both

And you can use direct filter to do what you want.

Example: 

const array = [your array here]

const filterarray = array.filter((item) => item.highest > 5.9))
console.log(filterarray)
```

Answer: you will get only 3 array back that has high higher than 5.9.

```
(3)[{...},{...},{...}
```

If you want to convert the array to string you can use also JSON.stringify.

I hope I could help!

Cheers,
Marcelo

Comment: Thank you so much Marcelo!! You didn't only answer the initiate question, but also predicted what will be my next question :D I've been struggling with it for so long. Much love.

Comment: P.S.: If I want to use the direct filter, is there a way to copy the  JSON string content into an array automatically, with no need to copypaste it manually?

Comment: I would guess this: `const json=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions).getContentText();`

Answer (score 1):

```
    function jtoa() {
  const json = '[{"average":5.76,"date":"2021-03-16","highest":5.88,"lowest":5.41,"order_count":2214,"volume":5093879501},{"average":5.88,"date":"2021-03-17","highest":5.92,"lowest":5.46,"order_count":2285,"volume":3968980696},{"average":5.68,"date":"2021-03-18","highest":5.91,"lowest":5.6,"order_count":2219,"volume":3695305537},{"average":5.65,"date":"2021-03-19","highest":5.98,"lowest":5.59,"order_count":2192,"volume":3948557942}]';
  let obj = JSON.parse(json);
  let a = obj.map(o => {return [o.average, o.date, o.highest, o.lowest, o.order_count, o.volume];} );
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(a));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make the script to copy the JSON contents to your ```const json``` from the ```jsondata``` from my example? I am going to work with thouthands of same-type JSONs and can't copy past each of it manually

Answer (score 1):

so, you always get a JSON string object from any http request as above.
Then you need to parse it:

```
let object = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions));
```

As soon as you have your object you can do everything you want.
So, you can copy this object to another one using a destructor (...) operator:

```
let object2 = [ ...object ]
```

Here, the object2 is an exact copy of the object 1.
The filter command works as a copy but returns only the value that match the sentence. As showed in my answer above.

If you want to return to you a number of cases that the item has highest higher than let say 5.9, you can use the methods: map and filter together:
Case 1:

```
const json = '[{"average":5.76,"date":"2021-03-16","highest":5.88,"lowest":5.41,"order_count":2214,"volume":5093879501},{"average":5.88,"date":"2021-03-17","highest":5.92,"lowest":5.46,"order_count":2285,"volume":3968980696},{"average":5.68,"date":"2021-03-18","highest":5.91,"lowest":5.6,"order_count":2219,"volume":3695305537},{"average":5.65,"date":"2021-03-19","highest":5.98,"lowest":5.59,"order_count":2192,"volume":3948557942}]';

let obj = JSON.parse(json);


const obj2 = obj.map(obj => obj.highest).filter((item) => item > 5.9).length;
```

**It will return the number 3**.
If you want the answer to be an array with the values you just remove length:

```
const obj2 = obj.map(obj => obj.highest).filter((item) => item > 5.9);
```

**It will return: [5.92, 5.91, 5.98]**

So, these are only some examples. You can look more on the internet.

Cheers,
Marcelo